# To get all rows if one condition is null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question. I am trying to create a query where in I am passing a paramater p_effective_date. If we do not pass any value in this parameter, then I want the whole query to be executed without this condition.

i.e. `p_effective_date` is passed null then still the query should run to get the output.

if p_effective_date is null then the condition p`aam.effective_start_date >  p_effective_date` should not be considered

```
SELECT DISTINCT PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER "Assignment Number",
paam.action_code    

FROM 
PER_ASSIGNMENT_EXTRA_INFO_M PAEI,
PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM

WHERE 1=1
and PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID= PAEI.ASSIGNMENT_ID
and paam.assignment_type ='E'
and paei.INFORMATION_TYPE='Tal'
and paam.assignment_status_type='ACTIVE'
And paam.effective_start_date >  p_effective_date
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAEI.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAEI.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```

Comment: `And (paam.effective_start_date >  p_effective_date OR p_effective_date is null)`

Comment: You should avoid this old style of selecting from multiple tables and instead use a `JOIN`.

Comment: @daShier, you mean _explicit_ `JOIN`. (OP is doing _implicit_ joins...)

Comment: @jarlh, yes, the term _explicit_ was _implied_ by my use of the keyword `JOIN`. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the NVL function.
NVL tests for null, and if the value is null, it replaces it with another value (such as zero).

```
SELECT DISTINCT PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER "Assignment Number",
paam.action_code    

FROM 
PER_ASSIGNMENT_EXTRA_INFO_M PAEI,
PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM

WHERE 1=1
and PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID= PAEI.ASSIGNMENT_ID
and paam.assignment_type ='E'
and paei.INFORMATION_TYPE='Tal'
and paam.assignment_status_type='ACTIVE'
And paam.effective_start_date >  NVL(p_effective_date,0)
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAEI.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAEI.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```

Since `paam.effective_start_date > 0` is always true (provided that paam.effective_start_date is never null itself), then this WHERE clause will eliminate no rows when paam.effective_start_date is null, which has the same effect as the clause not being there at all.  Keep in mind that you don't have to use 0 in the NVL function, you can replace p_effective_date to a date that you know is always less than paam.effective_start_date, or with any other value, as long as it returns the correct results based on your data.